# How to change default Product Route in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Any ideas on what route it would take to change this URL:

```
http://domain.com/products/item1
```

To show and link to like this:

```
http://domain.com/item1/products
```

Current routes look like this:

```
root_path            GET                         /                               spree/home#index
products_path        GET                         /products(.:format)             spree/products#index
                     POST                        /products(.:format)             spree/products#create
new_product_path     GET                         /products/new(.:format)         spree/products#new
edit_product_path    GET                         /products/:id/edit(.:format)    spree/products#edit
product_path         GET                         /products/:id(.:format)         spree/products#show
                     PATCH                       /products/:id(.:format)         spree/products#update
                     PUT                         /products/:id(.:format)         spree/products#update
                     DELETE                      /products/:id(.:format)         spree/products#destroy
```

Comment: I posted the solution I ended up using here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23309468/2229277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to prepend the route:

```
get '/:id/products/' => 'spree/products#show', as: :product
```

to your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: This works but doesn't change the of the products. In other-words both: domain.com/item1/products and domain.com/products/item1 work fine. Is there a way to do the route so that rewrites the current urls to go to the new route and removes the old route all together?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up creating a more targeted question and I think a better solution is listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23309468/2229277 - In case anyone was struggling with this same issue.